# Google sheets Query to return value based on earliest associated date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet that has a Google Form result tab which tracks client contacts.  When a new client is added with status of "New", I want that client on a list.  The kicker is I only want clients who were new in a specific month.  The problem exists because clients remain "New" until we actually speak with them, and every contact attempted gets added to the log with status still at "New".

The Google Form entries go into the Log tab.  Column B is the client name, Column N is our employee's name, column C is the status, and Column E is the contact date.

In the sheet I want the results, cell C3 is the first of the given month I'm trying to pull data for.

Here's the formula I'm currently using:

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(QUERY(Log!B2:N1001070,"select B where (N = ""Bob"" and C = ""New"" and E >= date '"&TEXT(C3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E <= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(C3,0),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') limit 50",0)))
```

As long as we communicate with the client in the same month we received them, this formula works fine.  However, say we received the client lead in February, but still haven't spoken with them and it's now March.  That client is showing up in the March results as if it's a new lead in March, when it's actually from February.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet showing how your data is organized?

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.